# Displaying Important To Do's In Index View

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, posting

Fresh learning rails, be gentle. No programming experience, but learning.

Building simple app: An app that asks "what's the most important thing you can do right now," gives you an answer field, submits it, and then displays the stored important things.

Ideally, they won't be stored on the index page, but for learning purposes, I'm trying to get them to do this.

Controller code:

```
class FacilitatesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @facilitate = Facilitate.all
  end

  def new
    @facilitate = Facilitate.new
  end

  def create
    @facilitate = Facilitate.new(params[:facilitates])
    @facilitate.save
    redirect_to @facilitate
  end

  private

  def facilitate_params
    params.require(:facilitate).permit(:answer)
  end

  def show 
    @facilitate = Facilitate.find(params[:id])
  end

end
```

---

Index View code:

```
<h1>Impactful Task Elicitation</h1>

<h1>Listing Stored To dos</h1>

<table>



</table>

<%= link_to 'Store impactful tasks', new_facilitate_path %>
```

---

NEW view code:

```
<h1>What is the most impactful task?</h1>

<p>Store below, motherbiatch</p>

<%= form_for :facilitate, url: facilitates_path do |f| %>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :answer %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :answer %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%=f.submit 'Save Task' %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

So far, I can navigate from index, to facilitates/new, and answer the question, to store my important to do. It then takes me to facilitates/33 (ID I'm assuming, or the number that I'm on, task wise)

I'd like to display these tasks both on the facilitates/33 (or whatever number it ends up being) page, as well as the index page.

I've followed directions on a similar type of form here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html but, I still can't get my stored To do's to display anywhere.

Any help would be awesome.

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller, you have the `show` method below the `private` line. That means that it can only be called from inside the controller, so you are being sent to the `show` template without that method ever being called (@facilitate will be nil).

Move the `def show` method up above the `private` line.

---

> It then takes me to facilitates/33 (ID I'm assuming, or the number that I'm on, task wise)

The line `redirect_to @facilitate`, means that after the facilitate is created, go to it's `show` method and page. The `33` is just a database reference for that particular facilitate, that it can be looked up again with `Facilitate.find(params[:id])`.

You didn't post what app/views/facilitates/show.html.erb looks like, but if you want to display the newly created facilitate, then it should have a line like this:

```
<%= @facilitate.answer %>
```

---

> I'd like to display these tasks both on the facilitates/33 (or whatever number it ends up being) page, as well as the index page.

If you only care about the listing, and not individual facilitates pages, then after creation you can redirect back to the index in the `create` method by changing `redirect_to @facilitate` to `redirect_to facilitates_path` (which translates to '/facilitates').

---

**EDIT:**

The `<%= @facilitate.answer %>` example was meant for the `show` view, not `index`.
On `index`, you'd do something more like this:

```
<% @facilitate.each do |facilitate| %>
  <%= facilitate.answer %><br>
<% end %>
```

To list them all.

Comment: All sounds good, and I've made the changes. Calling @facilitate.answer renders this though: undefined method `answer' for nil:NilClass 'code' 



<h1>Listing Stored To dos</h1>
  
  <%= @facilitate.answer %>
   
  <table>

Also - trying to get this to actually show up code in this comment response, but it isn't.

Comment: @RyanBallow I've edited my answer (the `EDIT` section) to address your comment.

Comment: got it!! That helps. Finally (with yours and others help) figured it all out. Now I understand what everything is doing. THX :)

Comment: @RyanBallow If your problem is solved, you should accept the answer to keep others from seeing it in the "unanswered" listings, we get a few points, and people are more likely to answer your future questions if they see you accept them.

Comment: Of course. Tried that immediately yesterday, and literally could not find that option/button. Either hidden or terribly unintuitive. Will try again.